# display checkbox input as text in a row created with JS, and delete that row

Tags: javascript

I have two problems with my vanilla JS exercise. I looked around the web and tried different code for two days now, and i'm honestly at a loss.

First, i have the checkbox input, where the user checks/unchecks a field. What i want is to have it written "yes" or "no" in a specific row field on webpage. The row gets created, but no matter what i try, it always writes "true/false" instead of what i want.

Input:

```
<label id="readlabel" for="read">Have you consumed the knowledge inside?</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="read" name="read">
```

checkbox gets created and appended to the table (id=myForm, table, tbody) solely with JS.

```
    let book = {
    ...
    read:document.getElementById("read").checked,
    }

    books.map((book) => {
    ...
    let td5 = document.createElement("td");
    td5.classList.add("checkTd");
    td5.innerHTML = book.read;
    row.appendChild(td5);
    tbody.appendChild(row);
    }
```

and the whole thing gets saved to local storage:

```
var existingBooks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("BookList"));
if(existingBooks == null) existingBooks = [];
existingBooks.push(book);
localStorage.setItem("BookList", JSON.stringify(existingBooks));
books.splice(0,1);
```

---

Next up, there is the problem of deleting table rows. Button gets created and appended with JS:

```
    books.map((book) => {
    ...
    var td6 = document.createElement("button");
    td6.innerHTML = "Delete";
    td6.classList.add("deleteBtn");
    row.appendChild(td6);
    tbody.appendChild(row);
    }
```

This button should delete the row of six cells on which the button is on. Again been trying different code for days with not a single one working. I hope the amount of code i pasted is enough.

Oh, and the code is organized as:

```
let books = []

const addBook =(ev)=> {
    let book = {...}
    books.push(book);
    books.map((book) => {
        "create and append"
    })
save to storage
}
```

Comment: `book.read` is `document.getElementById("read").checked` which returns a boolean value `true` or `false`. You can map it to `Yes`/`No` with [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) like this: `book.read ? 'Yes' : 'No'`

Comment: THANK YOU @Vitalii ! it's so simple now that you've explained it, and i can't believe i've written functions for this :/ that's learning for you.

Answer (score 0):

To delete row [removeChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) DOM method can be used like this: `elementToDelete.parentNode.removeChild(elementToDelete)`.

The only challenge it to navigate from `Delete` button node (`event.currentTarget` in event handler) to the row node that needs deleting (in a reliable way).

There is already a `row` variable so it can be used instead. Function arguments can be pre-filled with [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method, so current value of `row` can be passed to click handler.

Add `click` event handler to `Delete` buttons:

```
// the arguments get pre-filled using bind(null, row)
//     this will be `null`
//     row will be set
// event is automatically added by DOM when buttons
// are clicked and this function gets called
function deleteBtnHandler(row, event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();

  const elementToDelete = row;
  // alternatively
  // event.currentTarget (which is a Delete button)
  // can be used to find a node to delete
  // (add extra '.parentNode' to reach the needed element,
  //  needs to be updated when HTML tree structure changes)
  // const elementToDelete = event.currentTarget.parentNode;

  elementToDelete.parentNode.removeChild(elementToDelete);
}
...

    var td6 = document.createElement("button");
    td6.innerHTML = "Delete";
    td6.classList.add("deleteBtn");
    td6.addEventListener('click', deleteBtnHandler.bind(null, row));
    row.appendChild(td6);
    tbody.appendChild(row);
```